# How to maintain URL that user entered

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

My iis folder structure is like

```
Default Web Site---->online and Accessing with www.sitename.com/online

Default Web Site---->trade and Accessing with www.sitename.com/trade

Default Web Site---->private and Accessing with www.sitename.com/private
```

Here the login page is residing inside "Default Web Site---->trade/Login.aspx".When user enter 
www.sitename.com/online or  www.sitename.com/private or www.sitename.com/trade he/she will be redirecting to the url www.sitename.com/trade/Login.aspx.

So my need is when user enter "www.sitename.com/online" he/she should remain in the same URL as www.sitename.com/online and not "www.sitename.com/trade/Login.aspx".So how can i maintain the URL that user entered.

Thanks,
Joby

Comment: When they type "www.sitename.com/online" redirection happens to www.sitename.com/trade/Login.aspx.Here Issue is trade folder is showing in the URL.So they not allowing this.Instead they want link should be "www.sitename.com/online".No URL change at all

Comment: Here issue is not about redirecting.Issue is, i should maintain the URL as static.(www.sitename.com/online) not (www.sitename.com/trade/Login.aspx) even after redirection.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do this is pass a parameter w/ original url in your redirect to login page, and then have login redirect you back to that original url

```
Location: http://example.com/login?ref=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffoo
```

Then after login, you read "ref" parameter and do a location redirect back.

Comment: +1 assuming the question is "how to return back to orignal page after login" and not "never show .../Login.aspx in Url"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using built-in membership provider, then you may use `[Authorize]` attribute, that has an functionality to redirect the user to original page, after user gets authenticated system will automatically redirect the user to requested page.

Or you may try following solution:

Something like this:

```
www.sitename.com/trade/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fsitemap.com%2Fonline
```

After user gets authenticated, you may redirect the user to requested page.

```
Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
```

Comment: Here issue is not about redirecting.Issue is, i should maintain the URL as static.(www.sitename.com/online) not (www.sitename.com/trade/Login.aspx) even after redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using MVC or at least routing portion of it with ASPX pages to render views. This way you can have any Urls you want unrelated to physical file names.

Users rarely enter any urls... and I'm not really sure anyone cares as long as Url makes some sence (or complete noncense). So I think it is perfectly ok to render login page at something like /login and than redirect back to originating page. You can save original url in query string (as @chovy suggests) or hidden element on the page if login never leaves your site. If login leaves your site (i.e. for OAuth authentication) thatn session state or cookies may be place to store return Url.

Comment: When they type "www.sitename.com/online" redirection happens to www.sitename.com/trade/Login.aspx.Here Issue is trade folder is showing in the URL.So they not allowing this.Instead they want link should be "www.sitename.com/online".No URL change at all.

Comment: @JobyKurian, So using MVC's routing does not work for you either? Should be relativly easy to return either normal or login page depending on the state...